# Calling an ampscript function from javascript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Currently i have a cloud page with some ampscript logic, such as

```
%%[
set @rows = LookupRows("Outreach_global_Parameters","OutreachChannel",'SMS')
set @rowcount = RowCount(@rows)

set @row = row(@rows,1)

set @SMSVol = field(@row,"GlobalSMSVolume")
set @SUPSMSZip = field(@row,"GlobalZipCode")
set @SUPSMSBlackout = field(@row,"GlobalBlackoutDateSTR")
set @SUPSMSState = field(@row,"GlobalState")
set @SUPSMSsubcampaign = field(@row,"GlobalSubCampaign")
set @SUPSMScurdatev = field(@row,"CurrentdateV")

]%%
```

Is there anyway to wrap this in a javascript class so that i can call it from multiple locations?

Comment: Can you be more specific on the definition of multiple locations? Since you mention JS, I assume these being Cloud Pages?

Answer (score 2):

I would save it in a Content Block, and reference the content using [GetContentBlockById](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentblockbyid.htm) AmpScript function. This way you will be able to use this across emails, Cloud Pages and anywhere else where AmpScript can be used.

If you also want to execute it from locations not supporting AmpScript, you can place the code in a Code Resource within Cloud Pages:
[image]
Using this approach, you will be able to call the file using AJAX, whenever it needs executing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can just use the same script using SSJS syntax as

```
<script runat=server language=ampscript>
[INSERT AMPSCRIPT HERE]
</script>
```

where

```
<script runat=server language=ampscript>
```

is equal to

```
%%[
```

For more info check [AMPscript Function Calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/functionCalls.htm)